# What does "mon" and "kamo" mean in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, usage

I was reading a blog wherein this guy drew a new character. This is what he wrote under it:

> 以外にカワイイかもラブラブ 自分の人生なんていうもんに使ってるんだ...(;´д｀)ﾄﾎﾎ…

I am not entirely sure what the second sentence really means?
What does "mon" mean? And I sort of get the first sentence, saying that it's other than 'kawaii' but what does kamo mean? is it short for something?

Comment: 「以外に」は漢字変換が間違えています。「意外に」です。「意外に～～～かも（しれない）。」と言います。

Comment: ていうもん　＝　というもの　でしょう？

Comment: @virmaior　はい。もう少し口語的でない文章に変えると、「自分の人生を、なんというものに使っているんだ」という感じになると思います。

Answer (score 5):

もん = a colloquial version of もの

in this case, this is in the expression というもの

かも = a colloquial version of かもしれない

it means "probably" and is a construction often used to soften what one says before.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I still don't understand how the sentence translates over though. Could you please help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: @trentboyett Sorry but translation requests are off-topic on this site. Your sentences can be rewritten as 「[意外]{いがい}に[可愛]{かわい}いかもしれない。ラブラブ。(私は、)自分の人生を、[何]{なん}という[物]{もの}に使っているんだろう？トホホ。」 If you need further support please feel free to visit our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language), where translation requests are on-topic and it'd be much easier to communicate :)